# Email шаблон для outlook

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Верстаю шаблон для емайл рассылки и на outlookе столкнулся с проблемой.
Тег а - обычная ссылка не отображается как ссылка, виден только текст, без мозможности перехода, пример

```
<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" target="_blank">текст</a>
```

причем если ссылка на телефон и она работает нормально, пример

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="tel:+380971234569" target="_blank">+380971234569</a>
```

кто сталкивался с подобным поведением? как решить, подскажите плз

Comment: Выложите весь код, чтобы можно было проверить наличие ошибки и поискать причину проблемы

Comment: не хвататет таблицы и ячеек) table>tr>td>a+tr>td>a

Comment: попробуйте всместо `href="#"` указать валидный адрес перехода. Автоглюк ссылки, которые неизвестно куда ведут, может игнорировать безопасности ради.